# ActionContext.getContext()).getSession() Error

Tags: javascript, java

i'm studing some codes for web Application. I receive an error in Eclipse about this part of code:

```
public class BookedHistory extends ActionSupport{

private static final String SUCCESS = null;

private static final String ERROR = null;

int bookingId, amount;

ArrayList<TicketBooking> bookHistoryList = new ArrayList<TicketBooking>();



Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();


PreparedStatement statement=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
String sqlQuery="";
```

What can you say about this kind of error? 
Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwjC7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your casting is wrong. You cast the `ActionContext.getContext()` to a `Map` which you then try to invoke `.getSession()` on.

Map does not contain method `.getSession()` hence the error you're getting.

Also I do not understand why you attempt to cast it in the first place. From the documentation https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html#getSession() this will readily return a Map hence there is no need to cast it.

Just do `ActionContext.getContext().getSession()`.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, if i delete (Map) i receive this error:
Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getSession() is undefined for the type Object
 - Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be 
  parameterized

Comment: It's excepted as you're trying to store the result into a raw type `Map`. The return of the method is `Map<String, Object>` as mentioned above. Just correct the left hand side of the assignment to use the generic type. Try something like `Map<String, Object> session= ActionContext.getContext().getSession()`

Comment: Map<String, Object> session= ActionContext.getContext().getSession() I tried this but i receive an error

Comment: The method getSession() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Can you please edit your original code and post what you do at the moment?

Comment: Can you please post the full error as well? Maybe a screenshot would also be helpful.

Comment: Done! I have upload the image Thanks